# Android Support Design TabLayout: Gravity Center and Mode Scrollable

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, gravity

I am trying to use the new Design TabLayout in my project. I want the layout to adapt to every screen size and orientation, but it can be seen correctly in one orientation.

I am dealing with Gravity and Mode setting my tabLayout as:

```
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
```

So I expect that if there is no room, the tabLayout is scrollable, but if there is room, it is centered.

From the guides:

> public static final int GRAVITY_CENTER Gravity used to lay out the
>   tabs in the center of the TabLayout.
>
> public static final int GRAVITY_FILL Gravity used to fill the
>   TabLayout as much as possible. This option only takes effect when used
>   with MODE_FIXED.
>
> public static final int MODE_FIXED Fixed tabs display all tabs
>   concurrently and are best used with content that benefits from quick
>   pivots between tabs. The maximum number of tabs is limited by the
>   view’s width. Fixed tabs have equal width, based on the widest tab
>   label.
>
> public static final int MODE_SCROLLABLE Scrollable tabs display a
>   subset of tabs at any given moment, and can contain longer tab labels
>   and a larger number of tabs. They are best used for browsing contexts
>   in touch interfaces when users don’t need to directly compare the tab
>   labels.

So GRAVITY_FILL is compatible only with MODE_FIXED but, at is doesn't specify anything for GRAVITY_CENTER, I expect it to be compatible with MODE_SCROLLABLE, but this is what I get using GRAVITY_CENTER and MODE_SCROLLABLE

[image]

So it is using SCROLLABLE in both orientations, but it is not using GRAVITY_CENTER.

This is what I would expect for landscape; but to have this, I need to set MODE_FIXED, so what I get in portrait is:

[image]

Why is GRAVITY_CENTER not working for SCROLLABLE if the tabLayout fits the screen?
Is there any way to set gravity and mode dynamically (and to see what I am expecting)?

Thank you very much!

EDITED: This is the Layout of my TabLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/orange_pager"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: @Fighter42 did you found any solution to this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: The only way I found was getting the size of your tabs (manually) and then configure the layout parameters dinamically depending if it fits or not.

Comment: @Fighter42, can you post some sample code for the solution that you are using?

Comment: I know that my answer is not a good for logical but it helps me. 

Put some spaces before and after text. Then it will be scrollable. in both mode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I didn't find why does this behaviour happen I have used the following code:

```
float myTabLayoutSize = 360;
if (DeviceInfo.getWidthDP(this) >= myTabLayoutSize ){
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
} else {
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
}
```

Basically, I have to calculate manually the width of my tabLayout and then I set the Tab Mode depending on if the tabLayout fits in the device or not.

The reason why I get the size of the layout manually is because not all the tabs have the same width in Scrollable mode, and this could provoke that some names use 2 lines as it happened to me in the example.

Comment: With this solution the text could potentially be shrinked and using 2 lines as well. See other answers and solutions in this thread about it. You are reducing the risk of this appearing but will appear often anyway when the TabLayout is a little bit smaller than the screenWidth.

Answer (score 146):

Tab gravity only effects `MODE_FIXED`.

One possible solution is to set your `layout_width` to `wrap_content` and `layout_gravity` to `center_horizontal`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

If the tabs are smaller than the screen width, the `TabLayout` itself will also be smaller and it will be centered because of the gravity. If the tabs are bigger than the screen width, the `TabLayout` will match the screen width and scrolling will activate.

Comment: I am using Material design for my app. I followed the sample from http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/ Tab scrollable is not working in Kitkat and Jelly bean devices. In lollipop i am able to scroll Tab but in other than lollipop devices Tab scrollable is not working but swipe is working fine. May i know what would be the problem.

Comment: This didn't work for me on API 15 / support.design:25.1.0.  Tabs were left justified when narrower than window width.  Setting  `app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` worked to center tabs.

Comment: It worked for me. Tabs are allways centered, but when they are not actually scrollable, they don't fill all the width.

Answer (score 21):

I made small changes of [@Mario Velasco's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616474/android-support-design-tablayout-gravity-center-and-mode-scrollable/32844200#32844200) on the runnable part:

TabLayout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/myPrimaryColor"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/myPrimaryColor"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            />
```

Oncreate

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        mTabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Dashboard"));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Signature"));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Booking/Sampling"));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Calendar"));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Customer Detail"));

        mTabLayout.post(mTabLayout_config);
    }

    Runnable mTabLayout_config = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
              
           if(mTabLayout.getWidth() < MainActivity.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels)
            {
                mTabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams mParams = mTabLayout.getLayoutParams();
                mParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                mTabLayout.setLayoutParams(mParams);

            }
            else
            {
                mTabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: This solution has the same problems I mentioned on the Tiago's solution.

Comment: This Solution work on tab without icon, what if I have icon with text ?? :/

Comment: @EmreTekin yes it works with an icon, my tabs had icons with text

Comment: `tabLayout.getWidth()` always returns zero for me

Answer (score 8):

keeps things simple just add app:tabMode="scrollable"
and android:layout_gravity= "bottom"

just like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
app:tabMode="scrollable"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent" />
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what the creator is asking for. The problem with this approach is that in scenarios where you have 2 tabs or 3 three tabs in phones where the text is small, you'll have a layout like the Google Play Store where the tabs are on the left side. The creator want the tabs to reach from edge to edge when that is possible, and scroll otherwise.

Comment: Same problem. U can fix it?

Answer (score 7):

Look at [android-tablayouthelper](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-tablayouthelper)

> Automatically switch TabLayout.MODE_FIXED and
>   TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE depends on total tab width.

Comment: But when tab Titles are dynamic. The text goes in next line. And If use custom Layout for tab. Text ellipsize at end like

Answer (score 5):

I created an AdaptiveTabLayout class to achieve this. This was the only way I found to actually solve the problem, answer the question and avoid/workaround problems that other answers here don't.

Notes:

- Handles phone/tablet layouts.
- Handles cases where there's enough
  room for `MODE_SCROLLABLE` but not enough room for `MODE_FIXED`. If
  you don't handle this case it's gonna happen on some devices you'll
  see different text sizes or oven two lines of text in some tabs, which
  looks bad.
- It gets real measures and doesn't make any assumptions (like screen is 360dp wide or whatever...). This works with real screen sizes and real tab sizes. This means works well with translations because doesn't assume any tab size, the tabs get measure.
- Deals with the different passes on the onLayout phase in order to
  avoid extra work.
- Layout width needs to be `wrap_content` on the xml. Don't set any mode or gravity on the xml.

AdaptiveTabLayout.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class AdaptiveTabLayout extends TabLayout
{
    private boolean mGravityAndModeSeUpNeeded = true;

    public AdaptiveTabLayout(@NonNull final Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AdaptiveTabLayout(@NonNull final Context context, @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AdaptiveTabLayout
    (
            @NonNull final Context context,
            @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs,
            final int defStyleAttr
    )
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setTabMode(MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(final boolean changed, final int l, final int t, final int r, final int b)
    {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        if (mGravityAndModeSeUpNeeded)
        {
            setModeAndGravity();
        }
    }

    private void setModeAndGravity()
    {
        final int tabCount = getTabCount();
        final int screenWidth = UtilsDevice.getScreenWidth();
        final int minWidthNeedForMixedMode = getMinSpaceNeededForFixedMode(tabCount);

        if (minWidthNeedForMixedMode == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (minWidthNeedForMixedMode < screenWidth)
        {
            setTabMode(MODE_FIXED);
            setTabGravity(UtilsDevice.isBigTablet() ? GRAVITY_CENTER : GRAVITY_FILL) ;
        }
        else
        {
            setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        }

        setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        mGravityAndModeSeUpNeeded = false;
    }

    private int getMinSpaceNeededForFixedMode(final int tabCount)
    {
        final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getChildAt(0);
        int widestTab = 0;
        int currentWidth;

        for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++)
        {
            currentWidth = linearLayout.getChildAt(i).getWidth();

            if (currentWidth == 0) return 0;

            if (currentWidth > widestTab)
            {
                widestTab = currentWidth;
            }
        }

        return widestTab * tabCount;
    }

}
```

And this is the DeviceUtils class:

```
import android.content.res.Resources;

public class UtilsDevice extends Utils
{
    private static final int sWIDTH_FOR_BIG_TABLET_IN_DP = 720;

    private UtilsDevice() {}

    public static int pixelToDp(final int pixels)
    {
        return (int) (pixels / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }

    public static int getScreenWidth()
    {
        return Resources
                .getSystem()
                .getDisplayMetrics()
                .widthPixels;
    }

    public static boolean isBigTablet()
    {
        return pixelToDp(getScreenWidth()) >= sWIDTH_FOR_BIG_TABLET_IN_DP;
    }

}
```

Use example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.com.stackoverflow.example.AdaptiveTabLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/text_white_primary"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/text_white_secondary"
        tools:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/Sottti/7828dd74f234c28fdffd8b6608c8b291)

Problems/Ask for help:

- You'll see this:

Logcat:

```
W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$SlidingTabStrip{3e1ebcd6 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-466,96} during layout: running second layout pass
W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView{3423cb57 VFE...C. ..S...ID 0,0-144,96} during layout: running second layout pass
W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView{377c4644 VFE...C. ......ID 144,0-322,96} during layout: running second layout pass
W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView{19ead32d VFE...C. ......ID 322,0-466,96} during layout: running second layout pass
```

I'm not sure how to solve it. Any suggestions?

- To make the TabLayout child measures, I'm making some castings and assumptions (Like the child is a LinearLayout containing other views....)
  This might cause problems with in further Design Support Library updates. A better approach/suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution I used to automatically change between `SCROLLABLE` and `FIXED`+`FILL`. It is the complete code for the @Fighter42 solution:

**(The code below shows where to put the modification if you've used Google's tabbed activity template)**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // Set up the tabs
    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    // Mario Velasco's code
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            int tabLayoutWidth = tabLayout.getWidth();

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            ActivityMain.this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int deviceWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

            if (tabLayoutWidth < deviceWidth)
            {
                tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
                tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
            } else
            {
                tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Layout:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

If you don't need to fill width, better to use @karaokyo solution.

Comment: this works well; switching between landscape and portrait does exactly what you might expect. Google should implement this in the default template for tabbed activity.

Comment: This answer has the same problems I mentioned in the Tiago's solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think a better approach will be to set `app:tabMode="auto"` and `app:tabGravity="fill"`
because setting tabMode to fixed can make headings congested and cause headings to occupy multiple lines on the other side setting it to scrollable could make them leave spaces at the end in some screen sizes. manually setting tabMode would give a problem when dealing with multiple screen sizes

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"       
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:tabMode="auto"
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the only code that worked for me:

```
public static void adjustTabLayoutBounds(final TabLayout tabLayout,
                                         final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics){

    final ViewTreeObserver vto = tabLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            tabLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            int totalTabPaddingPlusWidth = 0;
            for(int i=0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++){

                final LinearLayout tabView = ((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(i));
                totalTabPaddingPlusWidth += (tabView.getMeasuredWidth() + tabView.getPaddingLeft() + tabView.getPaddingRight());
            }

            if (totalTabPaddingPlusWidth <= displayMetrics.widthPixels){

                tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
                tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

            }else{
                tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
            }

            tabLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    });
}
```

The DisplayMetrics can be retrieved using this:

```
public DisplayMetrics getDisplayMetrics() {

    final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    final Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        display.getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    }else{
        display.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
    }

    return displayMetrics;
}
```

And your TabLayout XML should look like this (don't forget to set tabMaxWidth to 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"/>
```

Comment: This is nearly there but there are some problems. The most obvious problem is that in some devices (and most of slow ones) you'll actually see how the layout is modified and changed.

Comment: There is another problem, this approach measures the total width of the TabLayout to decide whether to be scrollable or not. That's not very accurate. There are situations where the TabLayout doesn't reach both edges while scrollable mode, but there is no room enough for fixed mode without shrinking the text of abusing the number of lines on the tab (usually 2). This is a direct consequence of the tabs in fixed mode have a fixed width (screenWidth/numberOfTabs) while in scrollable mode they are wrapping the text + paddings.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple example and it always works.

```
/**
 * Setup stretch and scrollable TabLayout.
 * The TabLayout initial parameters in layout must be:
 * android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 * app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
 * app:tabGravity="fill"
 * app:tabMode="fixed"
 *
 * @param context   your Context
 * @param tabLayout your TabLayout
 */
public static void setupStretchTabLayout(Context context, TabLayout tabLayout) {
    tabLayout.post(() -> {

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = tabLayout.getLayoutParams();
        if (params.width == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) { // is already set up for stretch
            return;
        }

        int deviceWidth = context.getResources()
                                 .getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

        if (tabLayout.getWidth() < deviceWidth) {
            tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
            params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        } else {
            tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
            params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        }
        tabLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. With a little bit change for my case, works like charm

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to add the following to your TabLayout

```
custom:tabGravity="fill"
```

So then you'll have:

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:tabGravity="fill"
        />
```

Comment: This is not what the creator is asking for. The problems here is the tabs will never be scrollable, and you'll get rid of space in the screen. The tabs will start to shrink it's text and eventually they'll get two lined.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(tabLayout_chemistCategory.getTabCount()<4)
    {
        tabLayout_chemistCategory.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    }else
    {
        tabLayout_chemistCategory.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class DynamicModeTabLayout : TabLayout {
 
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun setupWithViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager?) {
        super.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

        val view = getChildAt(0) ?: return
        view.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        val size = view.measuredWidth

        if (size > measuredWidth) {
            tabMode = MODE_SCROLLABLE
            tabGravity = GRAVITY_CENTER
        } else {
            tabMode = MODE_FIXED
            tabGravity = GRAVITY_FILL
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your actiity when you adding tabs in tablayout

```
 tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Sotti's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37005351/337141) is great! It works exactly as the basis component should work.

In my case the tabs can evolve dynamically according a filter change, so I have done small adaptation to allow the tabmode be updated with the redraw() method. It's also in Kotlin

```
class AdaptiveTabLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : TabLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    private var gravityAndModeSeUpNeeded = true

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b)
        if (gravityAndModeSeUpNeeded) {
            setModeAndGravity()
        }
    }

    fun redraw() {
        post {
            tabMode = MODE_SCROLLABLE
            gravityAndModeSeUpNeeded = true
            invalidate()
        }
    }

    private fun setModeAndGravity() {
        val tabCount = tabCount
        val screenWidth = Utils.getScreenWidth()
        val minWidthNeedForMixedMode = getMinSpaceNeededForFixedMode(tabCount)
        if (minWidthNeedForMixedMode == 0) {
            return
        } else if (minWidthNeedForMixedMode < screenWidth) {
            tabMode = MODE_FIXED
            tabGravity = if (Utils.isBigTablet()) GRAVITY_CENTER else GRAVITY_FILL
        } else {
            tabMode = MODE_SCROLLABLE
        }
        gravityAndModeSeUpNeeded = false
    }

    private fun getMinSpaceNeededForFixedMode(tabCount: Int): Int {
        val linearLayout = getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
        var widestTab = 0
        var currentWidth: Int
        for (i in 0 until tabCount) {
            currentWidth = linearLayout.getChildAt(i).width
            if (currentWidth == 0) return 0
            if (currentWidth > widestTab) {
                widestTab = currentWidth
            }
        }
        return widestTab * tabCount
    }

    init {
        tabMode = MODE_SCROLLABLE
    }
}
```