# Remove line break in TabLayout

Tags: android, xml, layout, tabs, android-support-library

I just added the new TabLayout component to my app. As you may know there are two different modes for tabs `app:tabMode="scrollable"` and `app:tabMode="fixed"`.

When I use `app:tabMode="fixed"` I get following result:

[image]

There's no margin/padding on the left and right side but the text is wrapped.

But when I use `app:tabMode="scrollable"` I get following result:

[image]

The text is not wrapped but here is a weird margin on the right side and I can't get rid of it.

I also tried setting the tabGravity to either `app:tabGravity="center"` or `app:tabGravity="fill"` but did not achieve any changes.

Would be nice if any of you smart guys and girls got a solution for me.

Cheers, Lukas

Comment: These are the two modes of the TabLayout. If you used fixed, then all tabs are the same size. Which means that there is less room for your tab 1 and 3. If you use scrollable, then the text is on a single line and the tab takes up the minimum amount of space and has a left gravity. For Android development, you shouldn't be concerning yourself with a single screen size anyway. Perhaps you should consider implementing something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31363206/2977237.

Comment: Why don't you try to create your own tab layout and manage accordingly. Use custom layout as your tab and give listeners to children layout.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One solution here is to inflate a custom layout for each tab, which will give you more control over the appearance of each tab.
This is done with the [setCustomView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setCustomView(android.view.View)) method.

Note that it will look different on different screen resolutions.

It's always tough to make it look perfect on every device, but at least using this method gives you more control, as you can use different custom layout xml files for different screen resolutions/sizes.

One approach would be to make the font size as big as possible without getting cut off on each screen size.

I got a simple example working, which restricts the text in each tab to one line, however in this simple example it also causes the long text in the side tabs to ellipsize without changing the font size.  Your next step would be to figure out the optimal font size for each screen size, and create a specific tab layout xml for each.

Here is the custom_tab.xml file, with `android:singleLine="true"` specified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the layout for MainActivity:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:tabTextColor="#d3d3d3"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#ff00ff"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Activity code, which includes the FragmentPagerAdapter:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter =
                new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
        }
    }


    class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Aufzeichnung", "Berichte", "Neue Aufgabe", };
        Context context;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
            super(fm);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabTitles.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new BlankFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new BlankFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new BlankFragment();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            // Generate title based on item position
            return tabTitles[position];
        }

        public View getTabView(int position) {
            View tab = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
            tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
            return tab;
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the result with the code above:

[image]

Note that if you remove `android:singleLine="true"`, it looks like this, similar to how it looks in your question:

[image]

Comment: Note that it is recommended in the Material Design guidelines that text size is intended to be `14sp` or `12sp` if it takes up two lines: https://material.io/guidelines/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs

Answer (score 42):

Here's a quick hack, a lot shorter than using `setCustomView()`: use the `android:theme` attribute on your `TabLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/TabLayout_Theme"
    app:tabMode="fixed"/>
```

Then in your themes XML:

```
<style name="TabLayout_Theme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>
```

We have to do it this way, because unfortunately the `android:singleLine` attribute is ignored on the `app:tabTextAppearance` set on the TabLayout. `app:tabTextAppearance` is really only useful for changing text size.

Comment: I haven't tried, but since the Tab layout /design_layout_tab_text.xml is hardcoded with `maxLines=2`, I don't see how this helps.

Comment: Simple solution and works even in cases where other solutions don't, unfortunately the `singleLine` attribute is also applied to the tooltip that appears when you long press a tab item. I tried to use `tooltipStyle` to set `singleLine` back to `false` but without success. Anyway this answer is the best workaround at the moment.

Answer (score 25):

Showing "..." in tab titles will not make a good UI experience I suggest that you should set **tabmode** to **scrollable** and let tab titles take as much space they want.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Worked for me.

Comment: The simplest solution

Answer (score 5):

If it is an option you could center the tabs with a RelativeLayout and by setting android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

This will give you an equal margin on both the left and right side.

e.g.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: my TabLayout gone if i wrap it inside RelativeLayout

Answer (score 5):

I have added:

```
app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
```

in  element.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you are able to remove the default padding. For me it worked to make slightly longer texts within one line

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
```

From here:
http://panavtec.me/playing-with-the-new-support-tablayout

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted, this is the great hack/workaround for handling different font sizes/accessibility options for fixed-width tabs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I found is by applying TextAppearance.Design.Tab style to app:tabTextAppearance. This will resize the font of that one tab, instead of breaking line.

Apply it to TabLayout:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab"
        ...
        />
```

Answer (score -2):

In your layout XML, if You are usign `TextView` ,use `android:maxLines="1"` or `android:singleLine="true"`
See if this works. And if Not `TextView` then please put your xml here.

Comment: As i wrote above, i use the TabLayout component from the Design Support Library. Here's my XML if you wanna have a look: http://pastebin.com/cLCvYTw3

Comment: I think it has an attribute named "textAppearance", you can define the singleLine state in a style file and set it to your textAppearance

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam TabLayout does have attribute `app:tabTextAppearance`, but it sadly ignores `singleLine` and `maxLines`. Instead it works for `textSize`, `textAllCaps`, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Solved my problem by assigning style to app:tabTextAppearance

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance">
```

style:

```
<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_5sdp</item>
</style>
```

You can set textSize also.

Comment: It won't work as required. TextAppearance uses only style attrs, see "setTextAppearance" source code in TextView. singleLine won't be used, only text size will be reduced.

Answer (score -2):

```
float myTabLayoutSize = 360;
if (DeviceInfo.getWidthDP(this) >= myTabLayoutSize ){
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
} else {
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
}
```

Comment: Basically, I have to calculate manually the width of my tabLayout and then I set the Tab Mode depending on if the tabLayout fits in the device or not. and its working fine for both cases.