# Android: How to fill tabs with scrolling in custom tabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-scrollable-tabs

I have a `tablayout` with 6 tabs. Tabs are fixed in the display but their text does not show completely. I do the solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601414/tablayout-not-filling-width-when-tabmode-set-to-scrollable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) so that I can summarize them in these lines:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

But it did not solve my problem. I also use custom `TabLayout` in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002684/tabs-dont-fit-to-screen-with-tabmode-scrollable-even-with-a-custom-tab-layout) and still I have the same problem.

Here are my codes:
I use a custom `tablayout` with this `custom_tab.xml` file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/tabIcon"/>

        <CustomViews.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/basket_badge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/notification_circle"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="8sp" />
        <CustomViews.CustomTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_inactive"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/tabIcon"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:id="@+id/tabTitle"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The first `ImageView` shows the tab icon. The next `ImageView` is used for the badge and the `CustomTextView` is used for showing the tab title.
Here is my layout file include `tablayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:id="@+id/avatar_tabLayout"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@null"
        />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way to set up `tab` width with Maximum existence tab size? Or any other solutions?

Comment: Do you want your tab layouts to be scrollable or not scrollable?

Comment: I want to be scrollable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get rid off

```
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabMode="fixed"
```

in your `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`

Replace it with `app:tabMode="scrollable"`