# Android Design Support Library: TabLayout tabs text in single line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-view, android-tablayout

I want to put tabs text(max 8 chars) in single line

[image]

I added a custom style to TabLayout element

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
</style>
<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>
```

Still it does not work out. I also tried

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
  app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance"
  ..
  ..
  />
```

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32547335/4395530) might be the solution that you are looking for. :)

Comment: Just add  app:tabMode="scrollable ;<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

Comment: solved my problem by this answer [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42851372/4101786)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just add `app:tabMode="scrollable"` to TabLayout;

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
app:tabMode="scrollable"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Once change the following code

```
<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>
```

to the following

```
<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: add this style as theme to tablayout xml

Answer (score -3):

Add this line to your TabLayout custom style, it will do the magic.

`<item name="android:maxLines">1</item>`

Comment: I tried using this, but its not working