# How to use android.support.design.widget.TabLayout to create custom layout of tab?

Tags: android

I found the below documentation on how to set a `customView`. But when I change the `id` in my layout to "text1" and "icon", `setText()` and `setIcon()` do not work.

> public TabLayout.Tab setCustomView (int layoutResId)
>
> Set a custom view to be used for this tab.
>
> If the inflated layout contains a `TextView` with an ID of `text1` then that will be updated with the value given to `setText(CharSequence)`. Similarly, if this layout contains an `ImageView` with ID icon then it will be updated with the value given to `setIcon(Drawable)`.

(Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setCustomView(int))

Can anyone give me an example of how this works?

Java code:

```
    TabLayout.Tab tabAdd = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
    tabAdd.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_custom_view);
    tabAdd.setText("Add");
    tabAdd.setIcon(R.mipmap.add_tab).setText("Add");
```

Layout Code:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/icon"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/icon" />
```

Comment: Worth a read. [Difference between `@+id`, `@id` and `@android` in Android](http://android-wtf.com/2012/11/difference-between-at-plus-id-and-at-id-in-android/)

Comment: You could alternatively inflate a custom view that you manage yourself, take a look here for a complete implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32547335/4409409

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the system Resource identifiers. That is, `@android:id/text1` and `@android:id/icon`.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@android:id/icon"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/icon" />
```

If you would need to reference these IDs in your code, they would be `android.R.id.text1` and `android.R.id.icon`.

Comment: I found some more information on this, for anyone who's interested. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id