# android material design click event on tabs

Tags: android

In My Android Project I am using **Material-design** for tab view.
I have :

**tab_activity.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   />
```

and java class file is:

```
public class SimpleTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_activity);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

With this I am getting the tab view..
But , here How can I remove the arrow beside app name?
and,  sliding tabs are working but when I click on any tab(tab1/tab2/tab3) click event is not working.why??

[image]

Comment: Working code here that you can use as a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698756/remove-line-break-in-tablayout/32547335#32547335

Comment: You're using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_tabs)` but you posted `tab_activity.xml` - which are you actually using?

Comment: There is how to disable swipe by finger, second awnser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s/

Comment: I don't think this question has been answered here, or anywhere else on the internet.  @Preeti, did user3553286's solution below actually work?  I don't see how it would work...  tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener only listens to the selected state of a tab (as a result of swipes), not actual presses on the tab's view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use this:

**MainActivity.java**

```
       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
            tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

            final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                    (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
            tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_simple_tabs, menu);
            return true;
        }
```

add a **PagerAdapter** class ,add the fragments..

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think this should work..

Comment: This no longer works with the error "PagerAdapter is abstract; cannot be instantiated".

Answer (score 0):

just set clickable=true for TabLayout

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that your issue here stems from trying to mix things into TabView when it actually isn't getting the hint of what you want viewed.

I suggest just using ActionBar if not actually using a sidebar menu for your main activity setup. Here I just have generic ones set up and you can load you fragment names in accordingly.

Inside of your MainActivity.xml

```
protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        Tab listTab = bar.newTab().setText(R.string.list_title);
        Tab generalTab = bar.newTab().setText(R.string.generalsettings);
        Tab faqtab = bar.newTab().setText(R.string.faq);
        Tab abouttab = bar.newTab().setText(R.string.about);

        listTab.setTabListener(new TabListener<ProfileList>("profiles", ProfileList.class));
        generalTab.setTabListener(new TabListener<GeneralSettings>("settings", GeneralSettings.class));
        faqtab.setTabListener(new TabListener<FaqFragment>("faq", FaqFragment.class));
        abouttab.setTabListener(new TabListener<AboutFragment>("about", AboutFragment.class));

        bar.addTab(listTab);
        bar.addTab(generalTab);
        bar.addTab(faqtab);
        bar.addTab(abouttab);

        if(SendDumpFragment.getLastestDump(this)!=null) {
            Tab sendDump = bar.newTab().setText(R.string.crashdump);
            sendDump.setTabListener(new TabListener<SendDumpFragment>("crashdump",SendDumpFragment.class));
            bar.addTab(sendDump);
        }

    }

    protected class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener
    {
        private Fragment mFragment;
        private String mTag;
        private Class<T> mClass;


        public TabListener(String tag, Class<T> clz) {
            mTag = tag;
            mClass = clz;

            // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
            // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
            // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
            mFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
            if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isDetached()) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(mFragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (mFragment == null) {
                mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, mClass.getName());
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
            } else {
                ft.attach(mFragment);
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (mFragment != null) {
                ft.detach(mFragment);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        System.out.println(data);


    }
```

Comment: I already tried with all this..do u know  ...android.app.ActionBar.Tab...   is deprecated in android-6??

Comment: If your Target is 6.0+, use this example as provided here: http://blog.grafixartist.com/material-design-tabs-with-android-design-support-library/