# How to add tabs to TabLayout in layout XML file in Android?

Tags: android, tabs

I have been studying Android for two weeks. Now I am developing my first Android project.

In my project I need to work with Tabs together with action bar. I know that is very common in Android. For action bar I am using toolbar with v7. I seriously know about action bar. But I have an issue with tab layout. The problem is I want to add tabs to tab layout in layout XML file.

For example:

```
<TabLayout>
//tab buttton goes here
 <TabButton1></TabButton1>
 <TabButton1></TabButton1>
 .
 .
<TabLayout>
```

I search so many tutorials about tablayout. But all tutorials define tabs for tab layout programmatically. How can I define tabs for tab layout in XML and define event for them programmatically by findViewById? I don't want to use button view instead of tabs.

Comment: You can specify a layout xml for each tab, that's probably the closest you can get to what you want. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698756/remove-line-break-in-tablayout/32547335#32547335

Comment: It is adding the tabs programmatically. Right ?

Comment: I just updated my question. Please check the xml I want to be.

Comment: Yeah, there's no way to do that.

Answer (score 27):

This should be what you want:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabMode="fixed">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Popular" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Most Rated" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Favorites" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Comment: A new package now: com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem