# Can't set multiline text in TabLayout android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, textview, android-tablayout

I can't set text with multi-line in TabLayout in my application.

How can I set text with multi-line in TabLayout?

I want to remove "..." in TabLayout text.

Comment: Add the code for tabLayout that you may have tried?

Comment: i use detault code.

Comment: Have you tried adding a textView to your tab and using multi-lines that way?

Comment: no i haven't use textview in TabLayout.

Comment: app:tabMode="scrollable" remove this line from your xml code.

Answer (score 0):

See below link that will help you to set multiline in Tab of Tab Layout

[Remove line break in TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698756/remove-line-break-in-tablayout)

or

set your custom text view like bellow in tab_item layout

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTabTitle"
    style="@style/wrapParentRegularFont"
    android:maxLines="2"        
    android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tlMyJobCart"
    style="@style/widthMatchParent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/color_radical_red"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

And then set your text view to Tab layout like

```
private TabLayout tlMyTabLayout;
tlMyTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tlMyTabLayout);
tlMyTabLayout.addTab(tlMyTabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.tab_item), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a customView (a textView, preferably) by doing this:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLines(2)
tv.setMaxLines(2); //set max lines to 2 
tv.setText("your multi-line text is here");
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tv));
```

In case, you wish to set customView to already added tabs, you can get the tab and set the customView (TextView) to it:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tv); //postion 0, 1, 2...
```