# Dynamically adjust height of tab layout in android

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I've implemented a standard tab layout with 3 fragments with custom tab view as mentioned in this [post](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout#add-custom-view-to-tablayout).

The problem is the titles in the tabs are very long in some languages. For example, "*Unsolved cases*" in Finnish language is "*ratkaisemattomat tapaukset*" which causes this:

[image: Tab layout problem]

Custom view implementation

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Tab Layout XML

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabTextColor="#fff"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="#000"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I understand if this is not recommended by Google in having a large text in tabs but the translated text is too long.

I need a way by which I can **dynamically scale the tab height with the length of the text**. I cannot give static height in the xml file. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698756/remove-line-break-in-tablayout

Comment: @ManojPerumarath Can you please elaborate more? I did not understand your point

Comment: @ManojPerumarath single line won't work as my tab mode is "fixed". I cannot have "ratkaisematt..." as my tab title. I need the full string to be displayed.

Comment: @ManojPerumarath You can see the image here https://imgur.com/SefQFtv. All the three tabs have "..." at the end which I do not want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32547335/5351055

Comment: try this answer

Comment: @ManojPerumarath This answer did not solve my problem. But thank you

Comment: I think this would be the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698756/remove-line-break-in-tablayout/32547335#32547335

Comment: Did u find any solution for this ? @MVK059

Comment: @AkshayShah No, I did not