# Autosize text to be fit on single line with TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Is it possible to somehow make the text smaller (only if necessary) for it to be fit on the TabLayout tab in a single line without ellipzising?

/Edit:

Basically what I would like to do is have the text in tabs on single line as is asked about in here [Remove line break in TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698756/remove-line-break-in-tablayout) but without the "..." in the end if the text was to be larger. In this case I'd want the text to auto-scale so that it would fit on a single line. Some people suggested using scrollable there, but I'd like the tabs to be fixed in one place, just so that when there's say 4 tabs and one tab has longer text, it would just have smaller text size according to the fit.

Comment: would probably be useful to add in an image and some code to show what you're trying to achieve, might help others give you a better answer. would be interesting to see if this would be possible though, can't think of a way that this would work but perhaps someone else could

Comment: @a_local_nobody edited my original question, should be enough I guess to say if it is doable with TabLayout or not.