# Custom TabLayout like Google Play Music app

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

I implement [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) to similiar [Google Play Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music) app.

- Portrait (Google Play Music):
  [image]
- Landscape (Google Play Music):
  [image]

This is my layout :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

My code to handle TabLayout :

```
private void init() {
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Category 1"));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Category 2"));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Category 3"));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Category 4"));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Category 5"));
    mTabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
}
```

But result is TabLayout doensn't have margin on the left :

- Portrait (my example)::
  [image]
- Landscape (my example):
  [image]

I try this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616474/android-support-design-tablayout-gravity-center-and-mode-scrollable) but the result is not as expect. How can i custom TabLayout like Google Play Music app as show above ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `android:marginLeft` to the TabLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

To have different margins for portrait and landscape orientations, use separate values at values/dimens.xml and values-land/dimens.xml

Update:

Using margin makes a space, even when the tab is scrolled. So use padding, with `clipToPadding="false"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried add marinLeft or paddingLeft, when i scroll it make a space on the left screen, not as expect.

Comment: Yeah , it worked with  android:paddingLeft="16dp" and android:clipToPadding="false"> VOte for your answer. Thank you.