# changing android tablayout gravity

Tags: android, android-layout

I am going to implement scrolling feature to my `TabLayout`. It is scrolling successfully but the tab gravity is not working at all. My tabs are aligned to right side of the view. I want to show those tabes in the central position or at least fill the layout_width.

I added my codes below. Please suggest the possible way to make things working.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and here is the screen shot of the tablayout.

[image]

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616474/android-support-design-tablayout-gravity-center-and-mode-scrollable

Comment: @prakash neither android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" nor app:tabGravity="fill" worked for me. I saw the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

The magic resides on the gravity mode, in your case you want the `GRAVITY_CENTER`. Change your code to this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="center"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```